# iOS : Audio cannot be routed to bluetooth after GSM call

Tags: ios, bluetooth, avfoundation, core-audio, avaudiosession

I want to use bluetooth headset when it is connected. Everything works fine, sound is routed to bluetooth and bluetooth microphone is working. 
But after a GSM call, the application didn't route sound to bluetooth, and even closing the app doesn't solve this. The only solution for the problem is to turn OFF/ON bluetooth on the device and reconnect to headset.
Tested on iOS 10 and iOS 8.

Why this is happening ?

To demonstrate the issue I wrote this simple code which prints available inputs/outputs to console :

```
    @IBAction func updateButtonAction(_ sender: Any?) {
    do {
        try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(false)
        try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true)
        try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord, mode: AVAudioSessionModeDefault, options:AVAudioSessionCategoryOptions.allowBluetooth)
    } catch {
        print(error)
    }

    print("Inputs : ")
    if let portDescArray = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().availableInputs
    {
        for portDesc in portDescArray
        {
            print(portDesc.portName, portDesc.portType, terminator:"")
        }
    }

    print("Outputs : ")
    let portDescArray = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().currentRoute
    for output in portDescArray.outputs
    {
        print(output.portName , " ", output.portType, terminator:"")
    }
}
```

after running this method I receive :

> Inputs :
>   iPhone Microphone Microphone
>   BuiltIn8XXPlantronics BluetoothHFP
>   Outputs :
>   8XXPlantronics   BluetoothHFP

and if I run this method after GSM call I receive :

> Inputs :
>   iPhone Microphone Microphone
>   BuiltIn8XXPlantronics BluetoothHFP
>   Outputs :
>   Receiver Receiver

If it's normal behaviour, how can I change current audio route to using bluetooth ?

Thanks you.

Comment: Any progress till now ?

Comment: Hello, @GeorgeVardikos, I've made a workaround for this. I added 
MPVolumeView with only route button to my call screen, and I can switch between routes with that button.
Hope this will help you too.